# Mocking web server for development

Tags: android, android-testing, mockwebserver

I'm curious if anyone uses a tool like MockWebServer for general development?

I've used MockWebServer to run instrumentation tests against. In a testing situation it's very easy to use because you can enqueue the response you want per test method.

I feel it could be useful for general development (not running an instrumentation test) where the endpoint hasn't been developed yet but you still want to start client side development and don't necessarily want to have a TDD approach where you run an instrumentation test every time you want to try out the feature you're developing.

Does anyone have experience using MockWebServer (or a similar tool) in this way? Are there any pitfalls to it?